# How to output binary stream from c++ console app?

Tags: visual-c++

Is it possible for a console app to return a binary stream instead of text?

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{




    return 0;
}
```

How to convert this code so that it returns a stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup binary mode in this way, for example.

```
   int result;
   // Set "stdout" to have binary mode:
   result = _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_BINARY );
   if( result == -1 )
      perror( "can't set binary mode for stdout" );
   else
      printf( "stdout mode is binary now" );
```